# How to extract values ​within a string look for variable values

Tags: javascript

how can I extract values ​​from a string that is highly variable:

this is string:

```
let texto='The trip takes <span class="length">468 mi</span> and <span class="time">8:18 h</span>';
```

I want to extract the values ​​the numbers that are the ones that always vary

- 468 mi
- 8:18 h

variant:

- 1468 mi
- 28:18 h

I've been working with substring but I don't have favorable results

```
console.log(texto.substring(15,5));
```

Comment: This string looks like it's comming from  HTML document therfore you could cimply get the innerHTML value of each span using something like `document.querySelector('span.length').innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

This would be a great use case for regular expressions! Consider the following regexes for first matching for miles and then matching for hours.

```js
let texto='The trip takes <span class="length">468 mi</span> and <span class="time">8:18 h</span>';

const miles = texto.match(/\d+ mi/);
const hours = texto.match(/\d{1,2}:\d\d h/);

console.log(miles[0])
console.log(hours[0]);
```

Now since your `texto` variable appers to be HTML, you might not  need regex since the HTML *might* be structured enough to parse by accessing the DOM.

```js
const miles = document.querySelector('.length').innerText;
const hours = document.querySelector('.time').innerText;

console.log(miles);

console.log(hours);
```

```html
The trip takes <span class="length">468 mi</span> and <span class="time">8:18 h</span>
```